# Magento Disabling Flat rate when free shipping activated

Tags: magento

Hi when it is above 25euros I need to activate the free shipping 
When it is above 25euros I have free shipping but i have the flat rate also on the screen 
Can anyone help me to disable the flat rate when the free shipping in activated 
I prefer to have done using the magento backend rather than changing the code
Magento ver. 1.7.0.2
Thanks

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled/

Answer (score 0):

First Goto `admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Shipping method`

[image]

```
Find here  Setting minimum order amount 25.
```

and after that try below link ,which `disabling other shipping method` 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled/

Answer (score 0):

Why use flat rates for your case.

i suggest use table rate and define 0 for cart total above 25 and your flat charges for range between 0 and 25.